# Ramping up and down arduino motor due to ultrasonic sensor input

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

Im working on an arduino robot that needs to follower a leader robot infront of it. The leader robot can accelerate, decelerate , and stop and my robot needs to be able to follow the leader without crashing into it.

I have my two sensors working however Im having a harder time integrating the motors to ramp up or down. Currently only one wheel turns on at a time for the right and left commands.
How can I appropriatly ramp up or down the wheel speed.

```
int SpRMotor = 5;  //speed Right Motor
int MotorA1 = 7; //Right Motor = +
int MotorA2 = 6; //Right Motor = -
int MotorB1 = 8; //Left Motor = -
int MotorB2 = 9; //Left Motor = +
int SpLMotor = 10;  //speed Left Motor

int TriggerPIN1 = 3;//right
int EchoPIN1 = 2;
int TriggerPIN2 = 12;//left
int EchoPIN2 = 11;

void setup(){
  pinMode(TriggerPIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN1,INPUT);
  pinMode(TriggerPIN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN2,INPUT);

  pinMode(MotorB1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorB2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorA1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorA2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SpLMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SpRMotor, OUTPUT);


  analogWrite(SpRMotor, 170);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, 170);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  }
void loop(){  

  int limit;
  int sampledata1, sampledata2;
  sampledata1 = distance(TriggerPIN1, EchoPIN1);
  Serial.print("distance1: ");
  Serial.print(sampledata1);
  delay(100);
  sampledata2 = distance(TriggerPIN2, EchoPIN2);
  Serial.print(" distance2: ");
  Serial.println(sampledata2);
  delay(100);
  limit = 10;
  if((15> sampledata1 >= limit)&&(15> sampledata2 >= limit))
  {
    Serial.print("True");
    forward();
    delay(100);
  }
     if (sampledata2  >= 15 )
    {turnRight();}
  if (sampledata1  >= 15 )
    {turnLeft();}
  if ((limit > sampledata1)&&(limit> sampledata2 ))
  { 
    Stop();
  }

}

void forward(){
digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorA2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(MotorB1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);  
}


void turnRight(){
digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorA2, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorB1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);  
}

void turnLeft(){
digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorA2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(MotorB1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);
}


void Stop(){
digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorA2, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorB1, LOW);
digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);
}
int distance(int trig, int echo)
{ digitalWrite(trig,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig,LOW);
  long timedelay = pulseIn(echo,HIGH);
  int distance = 0.0343 * (timedelay/2);

  return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed seams to be defined by a an analog write to `SpRMotor` and `SpLMotor`. You did that once (with value 170)  in the setup. If you use variables for that (e.g. `speedValueL` and `speedValueR`) you can change their values as you need it and write it to the PWM channels on each forward, backward, left or right statement.

A short example:

```
int SpRMotor = 5;  //speed Right Motor
int MotorA1 = 7; //Right Motor = +
int MotorA2 = 6; //Right Motor = -
int MotorB1 = 8; //Left Motor = -
int MotorB2 = 9; //Left Motor = +
int SpLMotor = 10;  //speed Left Motor

int TriggerPIN1 = 3;//right
int EchoPIN1 = 2;
int TriggerPIN2 = 12;//left
int EchoPIN2 = 11;

int speedValueL = 0;
int speedValueR = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(TriggerPIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN1,INPUT);
  pinMode(TriggerPIN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPIN2,INPUT);

  pinMode(MotorB1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorB2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorA1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorA2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SpLMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SpRMotor, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(SpRMotor, speedValueR);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, speedValueL);

  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{  
  int limit;
  int sampledata1, sampledata2;
  sampledata1 = distance(TriggerPIN1, EchoPIN1);
  Serial.print("distance1: ");
  Serial.print(sampledata1);
  delay(100);
  sampledata2 = distance(TriggerPIN2, EchoPIN2);
  Serial.print(" distance2: ");
  Serial.println(sampledata2);
  delay(100);
  limit = 10;
  if( (15> sampledata1 >= limit) && (15> sampledata2 >= limit) )
  {
    Serial.print("True");
    // Just my guess - do what fits for you
    speedValueL = 170;
    speedValueR = 170;

    forward();
    delay(100);
  }

  if (sampledata2  >= 15 )
  {
    // Just my guess - do what fits for you
    speedValueL = 200;
    speedValueR = 0;

    turnRight();
  }

  if (sampledata1  >= 15 )
  {
    // Just my guess - do what fits for you
    speedValueL = 0;
    speedValueR = 200;

    turnLeft();
  }

  if ( ( limit > sampledata1 ) && ( limit> sampledata2 ) )
  { 
    // Just my guess - do what fits for you
    speedValueL = 0;
    speedValueR = 0;

    Stop();
  }
}

void forward()
{
  analogWrite(SpRMotor, speedValueR);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, speedValueL);

  digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorA2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MotorB1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);  
}


void turnRight()
{
  analogWrite(SpRMotor, speedValueR);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, speedValueL);

  digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorA2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorB1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);  
}

void turnLeft()
{
  analogWrite(SpRMotor, speedValueR);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, speedValueL);

  digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorA2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MotorB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);
}


void Stop()
{
  analogWrite(SpRMotor, speedValueR);
  analogWrite(SpLMotor, speedValueL);

  digitalWrite(MotorA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorA2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorB2, LOW);
}

int distance( int trig, int echo )
{ 
  digitalWrite( trig, LOW );
  delayMicroseconds( 2 );
  digitalWrite( trig, HIGH );
  delayMicroseconds( 10 );
  digitalWrite( trig, LOW );
  long timedelay = pulseIn( echo, HIGH );
  int distance = 0.0343 * ( timedelay / 2);

  return distance;
}
```